# discrete distributions

Tags: discrete-distributions

Please help with explanations.
I tried with Pr(U=U) = 1-Pr(U<u) and similarly for V but i am getting the wrong answer.
The entity X is a discrete random variable with the following distribution
X:    0     1      2      3
Pr:   0.4   0.3    0.3    0.1
Let X1,X2,..,Xn be n independent copies of X. let U = min{Xi} and V=max{Xi}.
a. Obtain the distribution and its limiting distribution as n->∞ for U
b. Obtain the distribution and its limiting distribution as n->∞ for V
c. Obtain the joint distribution of U and V and its limiting distribution as n->∞ for U and V
d. Calculate the correlation coefficient of U and V when n=2